# Spark Plug Broke off in the Cylinder of Ford F-150

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, f-150

The electro shield and porcelain broke off in the cylinder when trying to replace the spark plug. I’ve bought and extraction kit and Cannot get it to work for the life of me, and do not want it to fall into the engine. If I towed it to a mechanic would they fix the issue? How much would it cost roughly?

Edit: the spark plug on the left is what I’ve been able to get out, along with the removal kit I was able to get from autozone. My problem is I’m not able to get the pins into place in order to pull the porcelain out.

[image][image]

Comment: Does that tool operate like this one? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl5rTzpYrlE

Answer (score 0):

The right mechanic will definitely be able to fix it.

The fix could be anything from a few minutes using a special tool to extract the plug, through to needing a replacement cylinder head fitting which will take a lot more time and a lot more cost in parts.

If you cannot manage to remove the plug yourself, you would be best to call local mechanics and ask their advice and get their hourly rate, then choose one to take it to.  Where you live will also affect the price.

Why don't you describe which tool you have and why the tool is not working.  Someone may be able to suggest something that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard many complaints on this matter and the fact you have an extraction tool titled specific for this engine family says it all! Now as to repair. In most cases I suggest to any person removing a frozen threaded bolt etc to get heat to the area then using PB blaster in the hole to free up the threads a bit before using a quality socket to attempt the removal. keep in mind some times a slight back and forth tighten/losen will make a difference.